# How do you display advanced custom fields on taxonomy terms?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

In my archive page I added the following code:

```
 <p><?php the_field('embed', $term); ?></p>
 <p><?php the_field('download_output', $term); ?></p>
```

On the front-end when i'm on the archive page nothing is displayed. There are values in the field when looking at the WP-Admin taxo page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for ACF terms: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/

And the term should be in this format: {$term->taxonomy}_{$term->term_id}

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to get value from taxonomy term

```
<?php  
 $taxonomy = get_query_var('taxonomy');
 $termId = get_queried_object()->term_id;
 the_field('Your_field_name', $taxonomy . '_' . $termId);
```

also you can find complete documentation for *ACF* [Here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/)

and you can use get_field if you want to store your value in variable then print it eg: `$data = get_field('Your_field_name', $taxonomy . '_' . $termId);` then echo the *$data* wherever you want

Comment: I added the code, however it shows the custom fields for the first post on my archive pages. It does not appear to be tied only to the taxonomy term.  My archive pages are for taxonomy and category.

Comment: `code`<?php  
 $taxonomy = get_query_var('taxonomy');
 $termId = get_queried_object()->term_id;
 the_field('embed', $taxonomy . '_' . $termId);
 the_field('download_output', $taxonomy . '_' . $termId);
echo get_field('embed', $term);
echo get_field('download_output', $term);
?>`code`

Comment: @mariomillions add ( **underscore _** ) between $taxonomy and $termId while getting field value